# How to render the elements before to filter elements with ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm doing a project which does a `get` of the `json-server`, and render them on the screen.

But when I added a filtering function on it, it only renders after I type a name to filter. I wanted him to render everyone and make the filter.

My Body.js (Where is my function of render):

```js
import React from 'react';
import './Body.css';
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

class Body extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      input: "",
      employeeBody: this.props.employee,
    }
  }


  getName = () => {
    const { employee, add } = this.props;
    const {employeeBody} = this.state;
    return employee.map(name => (
      <div className='item'>
        <Link className="link" to={`/user/${name.id}`}>
          <div onClick={() => add(name)} key={name.id}>
            <img className="img"
              src={`https://picsum.photos/${name.id}`}
            />
          </div>
          <h1 className="name2"> {name.name} </h1>
        </Link>
      </div>
    ));
  };


  ---
  getValueInput = (evt) => {
    const inputValue = evt.target.value;
    this.setState({ input: inputValue });
    this.filterNames(inputValue);
    console.log(this.state.employeeBody)
  }

  filterNames (inputValue) {
  const { employee } = this.props;
  this.setState({
    employeeBody: employee.filter(item => 
       item.name.includes(inputValue))
  });
  }
---

  render() {
    return (
    <div>
      <div className="body">
        {this.getName()}
      </div> 
      <div className='input'>
        <input type="text" onChange={this.getValueInput} /> 
      </div>
    </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Body;
```

My App.js (Where i get the state by `get` of axios.):

```js
import React from 'react';
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route
} from "react-router-dom";
import './App.css';
import axios from 'axios';
import Body from './Body';
import User from './User';
import Header from './Header';


class AppRouter extends React.Component {
  state = {
    employeeCurrent: [],
    employee: []
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    axios
      .get("http://127.0.0.1:3004/employee")
      .then(response => this.setState({
        employee: response.data
      }));
  }

  add = name => {
    this.setState(prevState => {
      const copy = prevState.employeeCurrent.slice(1);
      copy.push(name);
      return {
        employeeCurrent: copy
      };
    });
  };

  render() {
    return ( <
      Router >
      <
      div className = "router" >
      <
      Header / >
      <
      Route exact path = "/"
      render = {
        props => ( <
          Body { ...props
          }
          add = {
            this.add
          }
          employee = {
            this.state.employee
          }
          employeeCurrent = {
            this.state.employeeCurrent
          }
          />
        )
      }
      /> <
      Route path = "/user/:id"
      component = {
        props => ( <
          User { ...props
          }
          employee = {
            this.state.employee
          }
          employeeCurrent = {
            this.state.employeeCurrent
          }
          />
        )
      }
      /> <
      /div> <
      /Router>
    );
  }
}
export default AppRouter;
```

Someone would can help me ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should filter in the render method.

```
render() {
  const { employee: employees } = this.props; // rename the variable {employee} to plural {employees}, it has more sense.
  const { input } = this.state;
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="body">
        {employees
          .filter(employee => employee.name.includes(input))
          .map(employee => {
            <div className='item'>
              <Link className="link" to={`/user/${employee.id}`}>
                <div onClick={() => add(employee)} key={employee.id}>
                  <img className="img"
                    src={`https://picsum.photos/${employee.id}`}
                  />
                </div>
                <h1 className="name2"> {employee.name} </h1>
              </Link>
            </div>
          })}
      </div>
      <div className='input'>
        <input type="text" onChange={(e) => this.setState({ input: e.target.value })} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Remember that the method `includes` is case sensitive, it should be lowerCase it before to compare.

P.S.: You could also create a variable / component / function and render split all the "logic" of rendering there.

Comment: Hello, thanks very much <3  But i have a question, why inside of the render ?

Comment: Giving that error:
`./src/Body.js
  Line 58:  Unexpected use of 'name'  no-restricted-globals
  Line 59:  'add' is not defined      no-undef
  Line 59:  Unexpected use of 'name'  no-restricted-globals
  Line 59:  Unexpected use of 'name'  no-restricted-globals
  Line 61:  Unexpected use of 'name'  no-restricted-globals
  Line 64:  Unexpected use of 'name'  no-restricted-globals

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.`

Comment: I did this: `return employee.filter(employee => employee.name.includes(input)).map(name =>..` now it's working, but your help was essential.

Comment: Yes, my bad @jota with the `name` I forget to change to `employee`. Also talking about why is better inside of the render, it was the same Dan which said that computed values shouldn't be in the state if we can calculate with the props in the render method. (I will try to looking for the link of that comment )